$p$, $q$ relatively prime s.t. $p^2+3q^2$ is a cube. Then $p+q\sqrt{-3}=(a+b\sqrt{-3})^3$
I'm reading a proof on Fermat's Last Theorem for the case $n=3$ and the author uses the following lemma:
Let $p$ and $q$ be relatively prime numbers such that $p^2+3q^2$ is a cube. Then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $p+q\sqrt{-3} = (a+b\sqrt{-3})^3$.
The author references "Edwards, Harold M.“Fermat’s Last Theorem: A Genetic Introduction
to Algebraic Number Theory.” Springer-Verlag. New York. 1977." for a proof. However, the proof in this book is very long and doesn't really use much abstract theory.
I would like to know whether or not there is a shorter proof of this lemma using number field theory.

how long is the proof?

That the conclusion has $p+q\sqrt{-3}$ being a perfect cube, and not just a cube up to unit multiple (in $\mathbf Z[\omega]$) is sensitive to the power being a cube rather than an $n$th power for other exponents $n$. For comparison, if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime integers such that $p^2+q^2$ is an $n$th power in $\mathbf Z$, then $p+qi =u\alpha^n$ where $u\in{\pm 1,\pm i}$ and we may not be able to absorb $u$ into the $n$th power (depending on $n$). For example, $4^2 +3^2 =5^2$ and $4+3i=i(2-i)^2$, but $4+3i$ is not a perfect square in $\mathbf Z[i]$ since its imaginary part is odd.

We work in the ring of integers of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, which is $\mathbb{Z}[\tfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}] = \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. This is in fact a Euclidean domain, so we have unique factorization of elements. Now, write:
$$n^3 = p^2 + 3q^2 = (p+q\sqrt{-3})(p-q\sqrt{-3})$$
Step $1$: First, we prove that each factor is an associate of a cube. Assume that $p+q\sqrt{-3}$ and $p-q\sqrt{-3}$ share some common prime factor $\pi$. Then, $\pi$ divides $2p$ and $2q\sqrt{-3}$.

If $\pi$ is not associate to $2$ or $\sqrt{-3}$, then it must divide both $p$ and $q$, but this contradicts the hypothesis that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.
If $\pi = \sqrt{-3}$, then $\pi \mid p$ tells us that $3 \mid p$. This further implies that $3 \mid n$, so $3^2 \mid 3q^2$ and $3 \mid q$. This is once again a contradiction.
If $\pi = 2$, then $p$ and $q$ must have the same parity modulo $2$. Since they are also relatively prime, they must both be odd. However, this would make $p^2, q^2 \equiv 1 \bmod{8}$, so $n^3 \equiv 4 \bmod{8}$, which is impossible since it tells us that $2 \mid n$ but $2^3 \nmid n^3$.

Thus, both $p+q\sqrt{-3}$ and $p-q\sqrt{-3}$ are associates of perfect cubes.
Step $2$: Next, we prove that each factor  $p \pm q\sqrt{-3}$ is a perfect cube in $\mathbb Z[\omega]$. These are conjugates, so we can focus on $p+q\sqrt{-3}$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $p+q\sqrt{-3} = (a + b\omega)^3\omega^k$ where $3 \nmid k$. You may replace $q$ with $-q$ if necessary to assume $k = 1$. Now, we have the equation:
$$(p+q) + (2q)\omega = (a + b\omega)^3\omega = -3ab(a-b) + (a^3+b^3-3a^2b)\omega$$
The coefficient of $\omega$ must be even. Since it is $a^3 + b^3 - 3a^2b \equiv a+b + ab \equiv 1 + (a+1)(b+1) \bmod{2}$, both $a$ and $b$ must be even, but this implies that both $p$ and $q$ are even, a contradiction.
Step $3$: Finally, we show that any perfect cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is also a perfect cube in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. (In particular, all perfect cubes in $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ are in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$.) First we will show that any element $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ has a (unit)  multiple by $1$, $\omega$, or $\omega^2$ that is in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. Write $\alpha = a + b\omega$ in $\mathbb Z[\omega]$. We have $\alpha\omega = (a + b\omega)\omega = -b + (a-b) \omega$ and $\alpha\omega^2 = (a + b\omega)\omega^2 = (b-a) - a\omega$. The possible coefficients of $\omega$ here are $b$, $a-b$, and $-a$, and one of these is even, so one of the three numbers $\alpha u$ with $u \in \{1,\omega,\omega^2\}$ is in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$.  Then
$$
\alpha^3 = (\alpha u\overline{u})^3 = (\alpha u)^3 \overline{u}^3, 
$$
with $\alpha u \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ and $\overline{u}^3 = 1$ since $u \in \{1,\omega,\omega^2\}$ is a cube root of unity.  Thus $\alpha^3 = (\alpha u)^3$ and $\alpha u \in \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$.

@Sil Good point! I'll try to edit my answer.

I edited your answer to change the integer coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to $a$ and $b$, so the Latin variables $p$, $q$, $n$, $k$, $a$, and $b$ are all integers, while Greek variables need not be integers. I also corrected the formula for the coefficients of $(a+b\omega)^3\omega$, as it had an error: the non-$\omega$ term was not homogeneous in $a$ and $b$ (well, $\alpha$ and $\beta$).  That led to no mistake in the later reasoning, which is based on the $\omega$-coefficient and that was correct.

Thank you so much for your response. My goal is to study this field in some depth but I'm just starting. However, I can understand your proof and I'm making sure I'm understanding all the details. For example, in the second bullet in step one, why does $\sqrt{-3} | p$ imply $3|p$? Is it because $3=N(\sqrt{-3})?$

@KCd Thank you! David, it's not exactly because $3 = N(\sqrt{-3})$. More precisely, it is because $p$ is not just any element of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, but an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, if $p$ is divisible by $\sqrt{-3}$, then it is divisible by the prime lying below it in $\mathbb{Z}$, which is $3$. Another way of saying this is that $p$ and $3$ are not relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (they are both divisible by $\sqrt{-3}$), so they are not relatively prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, implying that $3 \mid p$.

If $\sqrt{-3} \mid p$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-3}]$, then taking norms shows $3 \mid p^2$ in $\mathbf Z$. Since $3$ is prime, $3 \mid p$.

@Milten Yep, that was a typo, thank you!
